# redirecting traffic to the new site - best practices

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect

We have a web site up and are moving to a new site, with a more modern design and some jQuery/ajax features for better usability.
The old site is on IIS6 and the new one is on IIS7.5.
The old site is on domain.com and the new site is on beta.domain.com.
I want to test out how the load will affect the new server, so I want to begin sending users to the new site slowly.
I want to start sending every 20th user to the new site and save a cookie so that a user that was directed to the new site will always be directed to the new site and a user which was directed to the old site will always be directed to the old site, as long as we don't change a key and "reset" the system.
I was wondering where would be the best place to implement this behavior / logic?

Comment: You should probably do actual load testing using tools instead of using users as guinea pigs.

Comment: I would, but it's just not my call. Our server provider has a general objection to load testing tools and my boss is siding with them. I voiced my opinion, but that's all I can do. So this is the lesser of both evils.

Comment: Load testing by simulating 1/20th of your users won't be very helpful. I doubt your application has a linear load profile - so you won't be able to test throughput this way and extrapolate to your full user base. You MAY get an idea of general response time, but that's about it. I suppose it's better than nothing, however.

Comment: This blog posting gives an overview: http://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2009/09/17/measuring-performance-response-vs-latency-vs-throughput-vs-load-vs-scalability-vs-stress-vs-robustness/

Comment: @ScottE - I plan to begin with 1 in 20 and then raise that bit by bit. 1/15, 1/10, etc. I think that can give me a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about in global `Application_BeginRequest`.. as for the best way to do it, by far the easiest way would be a simple `Response.Redirect` and I can't think of any real downsides. No reason not to just keep it simple.

Comment: That would be a good way to go, but I would like to hear maybe other opinions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Application_BeginRequest seems to be the best place to put such logic for me. However I'd consider some issues related to SEO, I don't know whether if matters to you. You may decide to send 301 Moved permanently or 303 Moved temporarily HTTP response codes. Also I think it would be a good idea to detect a search engine crawlers and always direct it to the same version, no matter if old or new, as it might be a little confusing to them when they get different content form the same address depending on crawling server.

Comment: It will only be for a short period, but you are right. I will try and redirect bots to a consistant URL. Thanks for the comment!